# Location of full HTML POST form data in Golang

Tags: forms, go, go-gin

I am posting an HTML form to a Golang/Gin backend. The following allows me to access individual values from the form in the backend:

```
titleValue := c.PostForm("Title");
contentValue := c.PostForm("Content");
```

But I cannot figure out how to access the entire form object at once instead of hard-coding in each key.

How do I access it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out--my use of Gin was result in slightly different syntax that made most of the examples I found elsewhere not work.

I access it with `c.Request.Form`.

Comment: I have not read the Gin code, but my assumption would be that it has already consumed the request body so it is not available in http.Request.Form.

Comment: Actually, I think you're right. I'll amend my answer to remove that incorrect assertion.